# syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".00>0")

Tags: bash

Usign ubntu 18.04 my bash script returns the following error:

**syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".00>0")**

My code is as follows:

```
echo Enter the number of images to be exported per folder!
read imperfol  

echo Enter the path where the timestamp file is located!
read path_ts

num_images=$(< $path_ts wc -l)

num_folders=$(echo "scale=2 ; $num_images/ $imperfol" | bc)

if (($num_folders>0))
then
    echo control 1
fi
```

My intention is that I need to check whether "num_folder>0" in the if statement. And there will be following statements "num_folder>1", "num_folder>2" etc.

The very important point is that the num_folder is not always an integer.

Comment: You need to use the -lt or -gt syntax for numeric values, have look here: https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-if-statements.php

Comment: *"What should I do?"* it depends what the intent of your code is - the error is because with `scale=2`, the `bc` command is outputting a floating point value like `1.00` that the shell arithmetic expression `((...))` can't handle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because with `scale=2`, the `bc` command is outputting a floating point value like `1.00` that the bash<sup>1</sup> shell arithmetic expression `((...))` can't handle ex.

```
$ num_folders=$(echo "scale=2 ; 1.0 / 1.0" | bc)
$ echo $num_folders
1.00
$ (($num_folders>0)) && echo Greater
-bash: ((: 1.00>0: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".00>0")
```

whereas

```
$ num_folders=$(echo "scale=0 ; 1.0 / 1.0" | bc)
$ echo $num_folders
1
$ (($num_folders>0)) && echo Greater
Greater
```

Note that inside `((...))` you can refer to variables by name alone without the dereferencing `$`, so `((num_folders>0))` is fine as well. Also note that inside ((...)), the `<` and `>` operators are indeed arithmetic comparisons - rather than lexical comparisons as they would be inside "square" test brackets.

What you should do depends on the intent of your code - you can either use integer arithmetic everywhere - if that's not an option, then do the comparison in `bc` itself:

```
$ echo "scale=2; (1.5 / 1.0) > 1" | bc
1
$ echo "scale=2; (0.5 / 1.0) > 1" | bc
0
```

and use the result in your (integer) shell test.

---

<sup>1</sup> other shells, notably ksh93 and zsh, *can* handle floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Many thanks for the comment. My intention (and also the reason of this question) is that I'd like to check whether num_folder>0, num_folder>1, num_folder>2. And the point is that I must keep num_folder as it is, not as an integer! Because it will change the following operations. I mean num_folder=1 and num_folder=1.5 are quite different for the next operations.

Comment: @uguros without knowing what "the next operations" are, it's hard to give good advice. Be careful of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: steeldriver, you have a point. Let me clarify... If num_points=1, i will do a image_processing for folder xxx1 and that's it. But if num_points=1.2, i have to do the same operation not only for folder xxx1 but also xxx2 as well. That's why num_folder=1 and num_folder='any float between 1-2' are different for me.

Comment: @uguros so do the (floating point) test inside `bc` like I showed, and test the (integer) result (`0` equals FALSE; `1` equals TRUE) in your shell script